# Are any 2 groups of order 6 isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

So my question is pretty simple : Are any groups of order 6 isomorphic ?

I would say no, but I know that if the groups are cyclic then yes. If the answer is indeed no, could I please have a counter-example ?

Thank you.

Comment: What examples of groups do you know?

Comment: S_3 has six elements and is not cyclic.

Comment: A side note: the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ *is* the only **abelian** (=commutative) group of order $6$. It turns out the abelian finite groups are easy to classify and count. The nonabelian ones, not so much . . . :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know about permutation groups, then $S_3$ is a non-Abelian group (so not cyclic) of order $6$. There is also the obvious cyclic subgroup of order $6$. These are the only two groups (up to isomorphism) of order $6$.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that $S_3\not\cong \mathbb{Z}_6.$ This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is cyclic, whereas $S_3$ is not.